# Update Oracle database with content of text file

Tags: oracle, file, sql-update, sqlplus

I would like to update a field in an Oracle database with the content of a standard txt file.
The file is generated every 10 minutes by an external program on which i do not have control.

I would like to create a job in oracle or a SQLPLUS batch file that would pick the content of the file and update a specific record in an ORACLE Database

For exemple My_Table would contains this:

```
ID Description FileContent
-- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------
00 test1.txt   This is content of test.txt
01 test2.txt   Content of files may
               Contain several lines
               blank lines

               pretty much everything (but must be limited to 2000char)
02 test3.txt   not loaded yet
```

My file "test3.txt" changes often but i do no know when and would look like this:

```
File generated at 3:33 on august 19, 2016

Result :
1 Banana
2 Apple
3 Pineapple

END OF FILE
```

i would like the full content of the file to be loaded up into it's corresponding record in an Oracle Database.

Comment: This would be pretty straight-forward if you were allowed to use some wrapper code...  are you open to that?

Comment: i don't know that... maybe... what does it look like?

Comment: For example a small wrapper written in Perl, Java, C#, etc...  if you are interested, I can whip up and example, but it would help to know if you're on Unix or Windows

Comment: Ha, ok, I think i get the picture; i wasn't familiar with the term "wrapper code" but you are right, a little wrapper in c# would definitely do the trick... At first, I wanted to stay away from a "compiled" solution to keep it simple for the other user that could see what was going on with a little batch file... however, if you think that would be the simplest way to go, then this is what i am gonna do!

Comment: If you don't have another solution, i can mark your comment as "the solution"...but i don't know how to do it... i am new to stackoverflow!

Comment: If I had posted an answer, you would just check the grey check box next to the answer...  but in this case there is no actual answer to your quandary.  I think we try hard to keep things in pure SQL (or PL/SQL) but often times spend more time and effort for things a programming language can do natively.  If you know C#, you should be able to whip this out in short order.

Comment: Thank you Hambone... I'll keep it this way then...